# Combine two files using awk, my command is not working

Tags: csv, awk

I have two files, each of them has 7 columns, I want to combine those two files based on the same column values.I used the following files to simulate my issue:
File1 and file2 has one shared column, the keys.
file1:

```
key1 abc
key2 def
key3 ghi
```

file2:

```
key1 hello-world
key2 amazing-time
key3 happy-day
```

Expected output:

```
key1 abc hello-world
key2 def amazing-time
key3 ghi happy-day
```

Here's my awk command:

```
awk -F'' 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} ($1 in a){print $1, a[$1], $2}' file1 file2
```

My logic is:

1. reads file1, store its first column as array(array a) index and store its second column as the corresponding array value
2. processes file2, checks file2's first column is in array a's existing index or not, if it exists, print file2 's first column, file1's second column and file2's second column.

Unfortunately, it returns nothing, can anyone help me, what should I do to get my expected output, what is wrong in my awk command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `-F''` your codes should work.

Comment: `-F''` is to say the delimiter is an empty space, why it doesnt work?

Comment: @haifzhan if you want to use `-F`, you need `-F<space>'xxxx'` you didn't have `<space>`. another problem/mistake is, your file is space separated, but you set (assume you wrote in right syntax) sep as empty string. note there is no `empty space`, space is not empty. you should `-F ' '`, removing that part works because awk takes space as default FS, so we don't have to write it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks a million! I made such a mistake, it was supposed to be a space in the single quotation:)